# Baffling invalid Syntax with :

Tags: python

Can anyone enlighten me as to why im getting an invalid syntax error? Its just a simply data.py and yet i seem to be getting and error in line 3, with the : highlighted red. The same thing happens to any of the parameters with ('Mass':) in it. Apologies for coming across as clueless this is all still fairly new as i am trying to learn myself.

```
  Sun={
      'Name':'Sun'
      'Mass':1.989e30,
      'mu':1.32712e11,
      'Radius':695700.0
  }

  Earth={
        'Name':'Earth'
        'Mass':5.972e24,
        'mu':5.972e24*G,
        'Radius':6378.0,
  }

  Mars={
       'Name':'Mars'
       'Mass':6.4171e23,
       'mu':4.282837e11,
       'Radius':3396.2,
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma after the first element of every dict.

Answer (score 0):

The key:value pairs inside a dict must be separated by comma symbol.

You have missed the comma symbol after the first pair for all the three dicts.

See the corrected snippet below.

```
  Sun={
      'Name':'Sun',
      'Mass':1.989e30,
      'mu':1.32712e11,
      'Radius':695700.0
  }

  Earth={
        'Name':'Earth',
        'Mass':5.972e24,
        'mu':5.972e24*G,
        'Radius':6378.0,
  }

  Mars={
       'Name':'Mars',
       'Mass':6.4171e23,
       'mu':4.282837e11,
       'Radius':3396.2,
  }
```